# How to model a simple Workout app (Class diagram)

Tags: uml, modeling, class-diagram, class-design

I've developed a simple Workout Android app without uml class diagram in mind. Now I want to refactor it.

## How the app works

On the home screen, there's just a button to start an workout session. By clicking on it, a countdown of 10 seconds is fired, waiting for the person to get ready.

Then, the app will display several exercises, one at a time, with a break interval between them. Each exercise takes 30 seconds; and each break interval, 10 seconds. On each exercise/break, the app shows the following information:

1. A countdown timer of the current exercise/break;
2. The name of the current exercise or, in the case of a break interval, the name of the next exercise;
3. An image that illustrates the current (or the next) exercise;
4. A pause button.

Finally, when the workout session finishes, the app shows a GIF as a celebration. On this last screen there's also a "Go home" button.

## The UML class diagram

I've made the following UML class diagram to model this app:
[image: UML Class diagram]

## My doubts

However, I'm not so sure if this is the proper way to model the scenario described. I'd appreciate if I could get some feedback/review about it.

One of the main things that I'm in doubt of has to deal with the `WorkoutActivity` class. It has no attributes in the diagram because I couldn't think of any attribute for it in the way that I'm modeling this problem. And because it's empty, it's a little weird to me. I thought about using a list class (e.g. `ExercisesList`) to model the set of exercises, but I'm kind of stuck with this diagram.

Another issue is about the buttons, should I include them in the diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to represent.

If your model is meant for the domain of workouts, keep it simple: the buttons (the user interface objects) and the timer (execution context) would not be needed.

In the narrative you mentioned a "workout session". I assume that this is what the `WorkoutActivity` is about. So better be consistent with the naming.

You can think easily of attributes: it’s the date and time (and user account?) of the session: this could allow the user to follow his/her regularity in the training.

A more general approach would be to have a `WorkoutSession` composed of several abstract `WorkoutActivity` (caution: different meaning than in your current diagram). Each `WorkoutActivity` would be a specialisation: either an `Exercise`, a `BreakInterval` or a `InfoActivity` (e.g. `FinalActivity`, but why not also a `StartActivity` activity to encourage new users, and other occasional activities such as tips&tricks, or advertisement). Something like:

[image]

The constraint of having one break after each exercise does not need to be structural: it can be a constraint that you enforce when the session is composed or generated. This gives you more flexibility, if in the future you’d line to have a break every 2 or 3 exercises (e.g.:advanced users).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I thought that the timer was an important part of the UI, and since every exercise/break has a timer, I decided to include it in the class diagram.

Comment: About that general approach you mentioned, I think it would be represented with an inheritance: `Exercise` and `BreakInterval` are sub-classes of `WorkoutActivity`. Is that the way you thought?
However, in the app, the `FinalActivity` is not part of an exercise activity, so I wouldn't include it on that inheritance. (in fact, it's just a view class, because in Android development a view, a UI screen, is suffixed with "Activity". So you can think of "FinalActivity" as a synonym of "FinalScreen")

Comment: Last thing, you said that "[The constraint of having one break] can be a constraint that you enforce when the session is composed or generated". Does that affects the class diagram in some way? How would I represent it?

Comment: @EstevaoCostaG3 If the model is a design model and not a domain model, you may show relevant classes of your design, including UI and control classes. You can use [stereotypes](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class.html#boundary) entity/control/boundary to clarify the kind of class.

Comment: @EstevaoCostaG3 yes, [generalisation/specialisation](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html ) are the UML terms corresponding to inheritance.

Comment: @EstevaoCostaG3 In fact, the schema I was thinking of,  no longer relates exercise and break: so it maximizes flexibility. The break would be an activity like another. But this freedom does not prevent the app to systematically put a break after en exercise.  So the strong structural constraint is exchanged against a light behevioral constraint. The fact that final activity is different can very well be accounted for, having for example a duration property for controlling the timer, and performanceduration for the time counted as sport. But it’s just a suggestion: you don’t have to ;-)

Comment: @Christophe I think you might have forgotten to make the class `WorkoutActivity` Abstract.

Comment: @GeertBellekens what an expert eye!  Indeed, and it was even written in the initial answer's text.  So, if I show `perfom()` as abstract using italic, I should have been consistent and used italic also for the whole class.  Thanks for having pointed it out: diagram corrected ;-)

Comment: @Christophe Now I understand better your idea, thanks for providing the diagram. But regarding the `finalActivity`, there should be no `perform` method in it. The way that makes more sense, considering the app, is to associate it with `WorkoutActivity` class, with a simple association that has multiplicity of `1...1`. Because this is the last screen in the app, it's shown when the workout session is over. So that's what I would change in the current diagram.

Comment: @EstevaoCostaG3 No problem: if you feel that final activity is very different, you are free to keep a separate class: it’s your design and you are the captain in this regard ;-)  (by curiosity, if you finish this app and make it available on an app store, just post a link here: I have some kilos to loose and the concept looks nice ;-)